# How can I resolve "could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer "?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, yarnpkg, node-gyp, yarn-lock.json

I have been trying to install a package from GitHub for quite some time now and have resolved many node-gyp errors while trying. However, there is still one error that I haven't been able to resolve and that is:

> could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer

I have installed all the requirements and have **PowerShell**, **Visual Studio C++ 2022**, **Visual Studio Build Tools 2022**, and **Visual Studio Community 2022**.

The issue is that yarn can not use PowerShell for unknown reasons; therefore, it can not find Visual Studio C++.

Comment: The Visual Studio executables normally aren't in `$env:PATH`, perhaps that's the problem. Perhaps running your command from a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt fixes the problem (locate it via the Start Menu).

Comment: @mklement0 I run the yarn command in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and got the same exact errors as above!

Comment: @mklement0 should I config the ``$env:PATH?`` I am not sure why it can not use the PowerShell!

Comment: You can try, but isn't that what the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt does? I was only guessing that `$env:PATH` is the problem; perhaps the package uses a different mechanism (registry?) to look for Visual Studio.